# How to return a nullable struct?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a method that I would like to return either `PrefabItem` or `null`. However, when I do the below, I get an error:

> Cannot convert null to 'PrefabItem' because it is a non-nullable value type

```
struct PrefabItem { }

public class A {
  int prefabSelected = -1;
  private static List<PrefabItem> prefabs = new List<PrefabItem>();

  private PrefabItem GetPrefabItem() {
    if (prefabSelected > -1) {
      return prefabs[prefabSelected];
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

I saw that I could use `Nulllable<T>`, but when I do so I get the same message.

```
struct PrefabItem { }

struct Nullable<T> {
  public bool HasValue;
  public T Value;
}

public class A {
  int prefabSelected = -1;
  private static Nullable<List<PrefabItem>> prefabs = new Nullable<List<PrefabItem>>();

  private PrefabItem GetPrefabItem() {
    if (prefabSelected > -1) {
      return prefabs.Value[prefabSelected];
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

What do I need to do to get my method to return `PrefabItem` or `null`?

Comment: Have you tried a `List<Nullable<PrefabItem>>`? I believe you want a list that can contain nullable values, not a list that can be null, that does not make much sense...  See [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bH4LNw)

Comment: Yeah I have, I am getting the same error message.

Comment: Are you creating your own `Nullable` data type?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn you have to return `Nullable<PrefabItem>` or `PrefabItem?` in your `GetPrefabItem()` method too

Comment: As @KennethK. says, you should not define your own `struct Nullable<T> { ... }`. Instead, with `using System;`, the pre-defined type `System.Nullable<>` will be there for you. Note that the pre-defined `Nullable<>` type is very special, and it is not possible to get the same behavior for a user-defined type. Once you use the "true" `Nullable<>` type, the syntax `PrefabItem?` with a question mark, is just a sweet way of saying `Nullable<PrefabItem>`, but the meaning is the same. Then note that you need `List<PrefabItem?>` or `List<Nullable<PrefabItem>>`. Not `Nullable<List<PrefabItem>>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should return either `Nullable< PrefabItem >` or `PrefabItem?`

Example of null-able syntax:

```
  private PrefabItem? GetPrefabItem() {
    if (prefabSelected > -1) {
      return prefabs[prefabSelected];
    }
    return null;
  }
```

One more comment. If you need List of null-able elements, declaration of the list should be either:

```
private static List<PrefabItem?> prefabs = new List<PrefabItem?>();
```

or

```
private static List<Nullable<PrefabItem>> prefabs = new List<Nullable<PrefabItem>>();
```

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn yes because it is the syntax to tell it will return a nullable type

Comment: This all makes sense, I thought I had to create the struct `Nullable`, but that is built in as `System.Nullable`.

Comment: A struct cannot be nullable. You are simply marking the method in a way that it can return an object of type of the struct OR it will return a null object (not typed).

Comment: @Franck Perhaps it's the wording, but your last comment is confusing. Only structs can be used with `Nullable`. A struct itself cannot be `null` (i.e. the variable can't be assigned `null`), and not even `Nullable`, which is a struct , can be `null`--it [overrides the `implicit` operator](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,79) in such a way that it can't be `null`.

Comment: @KennethK. Yes i see the confusion. I used `nullable` when i meant `null`.